# concatenate columns based on blank columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2013

I am having three columns,- and / should be used as separator  result should come in new column(File Index-sub Index/Year),if sub index is blank then result should be (File Index/Year).

```
  SELECT 
[ File Index].[File Index]
, [ File Index].[Sub Index]
, [ File Index].[Financial Year]
, [ File Index].[File Index] & [Sub Index] & [Financial Year] AS [Composite Index]
  FROM [File Index];
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IIF function: `IIF(Condition;ConcatenationIfTrue;ConcatenationIfFalse)`

```
  SELECT 
[ File Index].[File Index]
, [ File Index].[Sub Index]
, [ File Index].[Financial Year]
, IIF(ISNULL([Sub Index];[ File Index].[File Index] & "/" & [Financial Year];[ File Index].[File Index] & [Sub Index] & [Financial Year]) AS [Composite Index]
  FROM [File Index];
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have both `MySQL` and `MS Access` listed, here are solutions for both.

For `MySQL`, you can use a `CASE` statement for this:

```
SELECT [File Index], [Sub Index], [Financial Year],
       CASE WHEN [Sub Index] IS NOT NULL 
             THEN Concat([File Index], '-', [Sub Index], '/', [Financial Year]) 
             ELSE Concat([File Index], '/', [Financial Year]) 
       END as [Composite Index] 
FROM [File Index];
```

For `MS Access`, you will use `Switch(...)`:

```
SELECT [File Index], [Sub Index], [Financial Year],
       Switch(Not IsNull([Sub Index]), 
                 [File Index] & '-' & [Sub Index] & '/' & [Financial Year],
              IsNull([Sub Index]), 
                 [File Index] & '/' & [Financial Year]
       ) as [Composite Index] 
FROM [File Index];
```